# Pandas - Replacing text in column with dummy values

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe that has some customer info as shown below:

```
Customer Name, Purchase Date
Kevin, 2020-01-10
Scott, 2020-02-01
Mark, 2020-04-01
Peter, 2020-06-12
```

I would like to replace  the Customer Name column with dummy values such as "`Customer 1`", "`Customer 2`" and so on. Expected output:

```
Customer Name, Purchase Date
Customer 1, 2020-01-10
Customer 2, 2020-02-01
Customer 3, 2020-04-01
Customer 4, 2020-06-12
```

I would like this to be based on the DataFrame shape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all values are unique use `index` values converted to strings:

```
df['Customer Name'] = 'Customer ' + (df.index + 1).astype(str)
print (df)
  Customer Name Purchase Date
0    Customer 1    2020-01-10
1    Customer 2    2020-02-01
2    Customer 3    2020-04-01
3    Customer 4    2020-06-12
```

If need convert unique values of column `Customer Name` use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
s = pd.Series((pd.factorize(df['Customer Name'])[0] + 1), index=df.index).astype(str)
df['Customer Name'] = 'Customer ' + s
print (df)
  Customer Name Purchase Date
0    Customer 1    2020-01-10
1    Customer 2    2020-02-01
2    Customer 3    2020-04-01
3    Customer 4    2020-06-12
```

Difference is possible see in duplicated values:

```
print (df)
  Customer Name Purchase Date
0          Mark    2020-01-10
1         Scott    2020-02-01
2          Mark    2020-04-01
3         Peter    2020-06-12

df['Customer Name1'] = 'Customer ' + (df.index + 1).astype(str)
s = pd.Series((pd.factorize(df['Customer Name'])[0] + 1), index=df.index).astype(str)
df['Customer Name2'] = 'Customer ' + s
print (df)
  Customer Name Purchase Date Customer Name1 Customer Name2
0          Mark    2020-01-10     Customer 1     Customer 1
1         Scott    2020-02-01     Customer 2     Customer 2
2          Mark    2020-04-01     Customer 3     Customer 1
3         Peter    2020-06-12     Customer 4     Customer 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `factorize`

```
df['Customer Name']='Customer ' + pd.Series(df['Customer Name'].factorize()[0]+1).astype(str)
df
Out[11]: 
  Customer Name  Purchase Date
0    Customer 1     2020-01-10
1    Customer 2     2020-02-01
2    Customer 3     2020-04-01
3    Customer 4     2020-06-12
```

Answer (score 2):

try using sklearn `LabelEncoder`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
customer = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df['Customer Name'].values)
df['Customer Name'] = customer
df['Customer Name'] = 'Customer ' + df['Customer Name'].astype(str)
```